October CMS - Tailor fields comparison problem
I’m using October CMS version 3.6.30. Tailor blueprints are used to define several content types.
What I want to accomplish is to set the “updated_at” field of a content type record to the current date/time, whenever a ‘fileupload’ or ‘entries’ field gets modified on the backend form. Currently, if I change an uploaded file or an entry selection on the form, the parent record (content type) keeps its current value of “updated_at”, despite the fact that the related records did change.
My current approach to accomplish this goal is to use the ‘boot’ method of a custom plugin, like this:
public function boot()
    {
// Extend the EntryRecord model for the 'Content\\Video' section
        EntryRecord::extendInSection('Content\\Video', function($model) {
            // Property to store old values before saving
            $model->addDynamicProperty('originalRelations', []);

            // Listen for the beforeSave event to capture old values
            $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave', function () use ($model) {
                // Reload the hero_image relationship (single file)
                $model->reloadRelations('hero_image', 'authors');

                // Store the original value for hero_image (single file)
                $model->originalRelations['hero_image'] = $model->hero_image
                    ? $model->hero_image->only(['disk_name', 'file_name', 'file_size'])
                    : null;

                // Store the original values for authors (multiple entries)
                $model->originalRelations['authors'] = $model->authors->map(function ($author) {
                    return $author->only(['id', 'title']); // Extract relevant properties of authors
                })->toArray();

                // Log the original values
                Log::info('Original hero_image:', $model->originalRelations['hero_image']);
                Log::info('Original authors:', $model->originalRelations['authors']);
            });

            // Listen for the afterSave event to compare new and old values
            $model->bindEvent('model.afterSave', function () use ($model) {
                // Reload the relationships after save
                $model->reloadRelations('hero_image', 'authors');
                
                // Get the new value for hero_image (single file)
                $newHeroImage = $model->hero_image
                    ? $model->hero_image->only(['disk_name', 'file_name', 'file_size'])
                    : null;

                // Get the new values for authors (multiple entries)
                $newAuthors = $model->authors->map(function ($author) {
                    return $author->only(['id', 'title']);
                })->toArray();

                // Log the new values
                Log::info('New hero_image:', $newHeroImage);
                Log::info('New authors:', $newAuthors);

                // Compare the old and new values (from the beforeSave event)
                $originalHeroImage = $model->originalRelations['hero_image'];
                $originalAuthors = $model->originalRelations['authors'];

                // If there's a difference, update the updated_at field
                if ($originalHeroImage !== $newHeroImage || $originalAuthors !== $newAuthors) {
                    // Manually update the updated_at field
                    DB::table($model->getTable())
                        ->where('id', $model->id)
                        ->update(['updated_at' => now()]);

                    Log::info('updated_at field was set to current date/time for this video content type record.');
                }
            });
        });
}

The problem is that, when testing (changing the fields on the backend form and hitting save button), the comparison between old and new values is not working. For the images, I always get the original old value (before and after saving). For the authors, surprisingly I get the new value on the beforeSave event and the old value on the afterSave event.
Can you suggest some solution? Or maybe I’m overcomplicating things and there is an easier way?
Thanks in advance.
